# how to reduce numbers' significance in JSON's stringify

Tags: javascript, json, number-formatting

I have an array with numbers (coordinates) and I want to display those using JSON like so

```
 JSON.stringify(array);
```

My array looks like:

```
[{"x":-0.825,"y":0},
 {"x":-1.5812500000000003,"y":-0.5625},
 {"x":-2.2515625000000004,"y":-1.546875}]
```

But I'm only interested in the first (lets say) 4 significant digits, i.e.

```
[{"x":-0.825,"y":0},
 {"x":-1.5813,"y":-0.5625},
 {"x":-2.2516,"y":-1.5469}]
```

Is there a way to easily ditch the remaining insignificant numbers?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Native [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) accepts the parameter `replacer`, which can be a function converting values to whatever is needed:

```
a = [0.123456789123456789]
JSON.stringify(a, function(key, val) {
    return val.toFixed ? Number(val.toFixed(3)) : val;
})

>> "[0.123]"
```

Comment: Great answer. Just a small addition in case you are converting a GeoJSON file: the above will not only transform the coordinates, but also all properties. Therefore I've added ```if (isNaN(+key)) return val;``` before the return statement, as the key in the array is its index.

Comment: Since `JSON.stringify` is going to convert everything to a string, what's the point of casting the output of `toFixed` to a number? I.e., why `Number(val.toFixed(3))` rather than just `val.toFixed(3)`?

Comment: To answer my own question: Because if the replacement is a string, `stringify` puts quotes around the replacement in the JSON, causing it to be interpreted as a string rather than a number by the recipient.

Comment: @EdwardBrey: that's correct, `Number(val.toFixed(n))` is a cheap way to round a number to n decimal places.

Comment: @georg Creating a string and parsing it isn’t cheap, but it is a workaround for JavaScript’s lack of a native rounding mechanism.

Comment: Can I `JSON.stringfy` 0.12 to 0.120?

Answer (score 9):

Use `Number#toPrecision` or `Number#toFixed`, whichever suits your needs better. The difference is that `toFixed` sets the number of digits after the decimal point, and `toPrecision` sets the entire number of digits.

```
var foo = 1.98765432; 
console.log(foo.toPrecision(5)); // 1.9877
```

Note that `toFixed` and `toPrecision` return strings, so you'll probably want to convert them back to numbers before JSONifying them.

Here's the obligatory [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision).

---

You can also do something like this, if you want to roll your own.

```
Math.round(1.98765432 * 10000) / 10000 // 1.9877
```

Encapsulated in a function, it might look something like this:

```
function precisify(n, places) { 
    var scale = Math.pow(10, places); 
    return Math.round(n * scale) / scale; 
}
```

Comment: Note that both `toFixed` and `toPrecision` return strings, not numbers. So, you'll need to cast (by prefixing with a unary `+`) to keep them as numbers.

Comment: @Dave, good point. It didn't really fit with my simple examples so I left it out, but I guess I should mention it.

Comment: Did somebody benchmark this? In terms of spead, does it slow down the stringify considerably? In some cases it could reduce 5MB of data to just 2.5MB. But if the stringify is 100ms slower, then it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

The first way that comes to mind is to pre-process the array to round all the numbers to four digits:

```
var array =[{"x":-0.825,"y":0},
            {"x":-1.5812500000000003,"y":-0.5625},
            {"x":-2.2515625000000004,"y":-1.546875}];

​for (​var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    array[i].x = +array[i].x.toFixed(4);
    array[i].y = +array[i].y.toFixed(4);
}

var json = JSON.stringify(array);

// json === '[{"x":-0.825,"y":0},{"x":-1.5813,"y":-0.5625},{"x":-2.2516,"y":-1.5469}]'
```

The [`.toFixed()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a string, so I've used the unary plus operator to convert that back to a number.

The second way that comes to mind is to process the string output by `JSON.stringify()`:

```
json = json.replace(/(\.\d{4})(\d+)/g,"$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of overkill, but this should work in all situations.

```
function prepareArrayForJSON(array) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (typeof array[i] === 'number') {
            array[i] = array[i].toPrecision(4);
        } else if(typeof array[i] === 'object') {
            if (array instanceof Object) {
                prepareObjectForJSON(array[i]);
            } else if (array instanceof Array) {
                prepareArrayForJSON(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function prepareObjectForJSON(obj) {
    var i;
    for (i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (typeof obj[i] === 'number') {
                obj[i] = obj[i].toPrecision(4);
            } else if(typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
                if (obj instanceof Object) {
                    prepareObjectForJSON(array[i]);
                } else if (obj instanceof Array) {
                    prepareArrayForJSON(obj[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy yourself

Comment: The number of answers to this question is, well, overwhelming. I think I like your option the best so far as it the most generic. I was hoping for additional argument options in JSON's stringify, but apparently this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Run over your array and apply the following to all values.

```
 value = Math.round( value * 10000 ) / 10000;
```

Another possibility is to store your coordinates internally as int values (multiples of 10^-4) and just convert them for output.

Comment: This is not going to work in many (most?) cases (because of the way floating point numbers are stored internally)