# Animate transition between values on amcharts svg bar graph

Tags: javascript, html, animation, charts, amcharts

I have a bar chart I built using the 'amcharts' plugin.

The graph updates its values when the a dropdown menu item is selected,

I am trying to get the graph to animate the transition between the values when it changes, currently it either resets the whole animation and animates from '0', or if animateAgain() is commented out (line 142 in js) it jumps to the new value. This code is called after the values have been updated:

```
// Animate between values instead of resetting animation?
chart.animateAgain();  // Resets animation
chart.validateData(); // redraws the chart with new data
```

I've searched the docs and google but can't find anything to help with this, anyone have any ideas or pointers in the right direction? Is it possible? Here's the codepen :

http://codepen.io/bananafarma/pen/yewbJQ

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use amCharts' own [Animate plugin](https://github.com/amcharts/animate).

It adds a new method to chart objects [`animateData()`](https://github.com/amcharts/animate#usage).

```
function updateGraph() {
  var newData = chart.dataProvider.slice();
  if( document.getElementById('data-set').value == 1 ) {
    newData[0].gain= 3.8;
    newData[1].gain= 8.5;
    newData[2].gain= 3;
    newData[3].gain= 1.9;
  }
  else if ( document.getElementById('data-set').value == 2 ) {
    console.log("yo");
    newData[0].gain= 2.6;
    newData[1].gain= 8.6;
    newData[2].gain= 13.8;
    newData[3].gain=  4;
  }
  else if ( document.getElementById('data-set').value == 3 ) {
    newData[0].gain= 4.8;
    newData[1].gain= 10.6;
    newData[2].gain= 15.9;
    newData[3].gain= 16;
  }

  // use Animate plugin
  chart.animateData( newData, { duration: 1000 } );

}
```

Here's your updated [working demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e5b7e755ec85b282612c7d60d25b97fa).

Comment: Hmm, for some reason the chart data values now (sometimes) have lots of decimal points added, meaning that when I have labels on the columns on my real graph, some are not displayed. 
I assume this is a json stringify thing..?   Although I tried adding this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9340239/4517209 (reducing the numbers significance) and still the same results, which makes me think it's animateData() - or a lack of validateData() ...

http://imgur.com/o2WUJX0

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to be able to reproduce this. Do you have a demo with such behavior you can share?

Comment: Doesn't happen 100% of the time but always after switching between data a few times, can't work out why, does look like some kind of string issue though. 
http://codepen.io/bananafarma/pen/ONPydR .

I found this property which would help, but giving it  value of -1 returns undefined in the middle of some numbers ( value of 0 works as expected though? )
 "numberFormatter": {precision:-1}  ( commented out on line 51)

Many thanks!